# Azure deployment with 2 websites is cycling for a long time

Tags: deployment, azure

I'm deploying with azure in visual studio 2010 and I have this problem when I have 2 websites.

With only 1 website the deploy runs sucessfully.

Help!!!!!!!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web.Azure1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="PT" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes">
        <VirtualDirectory name="images" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes\imgpt" />
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="pt.consultaclick.com" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="RO" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes">
        <VirtualDirectory name="images" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes\imgro" />
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="ro.consultaclick.com" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InternalEndpoint name="Endpoint1"  protocol="http" port="80" />
   </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

After using intellitrace and remote desktop found the following in event viewer:

https://picasaweb.google.com/112383217404623421937/Dropbox#

In system section:

NtpClient was unable to set a manual peer to use as a time source because of DNS resolution error on 'time.windows.com,0x9'. NtpClient will try again in 15 minutes and double the reattempt interval 
thereafter. The error was: No such host is known. (0x80072AF9)

VSP rejected attempt to use protocol version '3.2'.

The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId 'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.

Site 1 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the root application is invalid.

Error communicating with the Spooler system service.  Open the Services snap-in and confirm that the Print Spooler service is running.

The SLUINotify service terminated with the following error: 
The specified module could not be found.

Azure section:

An unhandled exception occurred. Process ID: 3024
Process Name: WaIISHost
Thread ID: 1
AppDomain Unhandled Exception
Exception: E:\sitesroot\3

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IConfigurator.Deploy(String roleId, WebAppModel webAppModelPath, String roleRootDirectory, String sitesDestinationRootDirectory, String diagnosticsRootDirectory, String roleGuid, Dictionary`2 globalEnvironment)
   at ConfiguratorClient.Deploy(String roleId, WebAppModel webAppModelPath, String roleRootDirectory, String sitesDestinationRootDirectory, String diagnosticsRootDirectory, String roleGuid, Dictionary`2 globalEnvironment)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.WaIISHost.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure deployment virtual directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836023/azure-deployment-virtual-directory) (same question you posted before)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I was parsing the request on host header (pt.example.com) and accessing from cck.azure.com so the host header was invalid (I should access from pt.example.com and have a domain that I bought redirecting pt.example.com to cck.azure.com).......

Comment: If **same answer has been deleted by a moderator**...why did you reposted again 40 minutes later?! BTW even question is duplicated (and you posted same answer there too) :| :| :|

Answer (score 1):

You should try to figure out what is causing the issue. Could you try configuring Remote Desktop and connect to one of your instance? Verify the Event Viewer to see if you have any errors or warnings in the Application log.

In these situations I often experienced a disconnect from the Remote Desktop session because of the cycling, but you should still try it and with a little luck you'll be able to find out the cause of the issue.

Alternatively you could try configuring the DiagnosticsManager to ship the Windows logs ever 1 minute to track down the issue.

Comment: After using intellitrace got the following exceptions: https://picasaweb.google.com/112383217404623421937/Dropbox#5748986433672311746

Comment: I'm seeing a security exception. Are you doing something special in the WebRole.cs, in the Global.asax (of any application) or in a page? Something like accessing the registry, writing to the event viewer, ...

Comment: Sometimes we write to a log file in the filesystem, thats all

Comment: What are you doing exactly in the WebRole.cs or the Global.asax? Calling a webservice? Doing something in IIS?

Comment: In the Global.asax on Session_Start i'm adding Session Variables an on Application_Error I handle the exception using enterprise library