# Azure deployment virtual directory

Tags: deployment, azure

Added a new azure deployment project to my web application and deploy was successfull.

After adding a virtual directory to ServiceDefinition.csfef the application remains cycling, so I deleted the instance using azure console and deployed again with success and with the virtual directory.

When I access the site I get a page with:

Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

After analysing intellitrace got this message:

https://picasaweb.google.com/112383217404623421937/Dropbox#5748710219235327730

In event viewer:

Warnings:

The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId 'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.

Site 1 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the root application is invalid.

File Server Resource Manager failed to enumerate share paths or DFS paths.  Mappings from local file paths to share and DFS paths may be incomplete or temporarily unavailable.  FSRM will retry the operation at a later time.

Help?

Comment: I just deleted all the instances and storages on azure console and made a new deployment ad it works. But this don't seem to be an elegant solution.

Comment: May I asks what was the objective to add the virtual directory and how did u configure it? Please add more info on how you added virtual directly because, I am sure u have done it wrong which cause this problem.

Comment: Added the virtual directory through ServiceDefinition.csdef <Site name="PT" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes">
        <VirtualDirectory name="images" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes\imgpt" />
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="pt.consultaclick.com" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>

Comment: also que goal is to have multiple images directories one for each country, and the application using them transparently

Answer (score 0):

This is what you shared and I think there are couple of concern. First I think your directory location will be correct when app running on Azure or you haven't added any content in your project that's why directories are present there..

```
<Site name="PT" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes"> 
<VirtualDirectory name="images" physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes\imgpt" /> 
<Bindings> 
 <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="pt.consultaclick.com" /> 
</Bindings> 
</Site>
```

Next because your are parsing the request on host header, which makes website to differentiate into applications so it is best to have Virtual Application setting along with it.

Otherwise you really need to have minimum two sites and set two bindings. One binding for your pt.consultaclick.com and other for any other remaining host header otherwise your site will serve very limited requests based on host header.

I like [this blog](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/11/azure-running-multiple-web-sites-in-a-single-webrole/) which explained this blog in serious details which sure will help you. My this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/01/windows-azure-how-to-define-virtual-directories-in-service-definition-csdef-for-your-site.aspx) has some info on this regard.